# Oracle SQL Loader - how do I replace embedded CR/LF in data?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

***Note: this is a revised version of an earlier question***

I have a text file that is to be imported into an Oracle table with SQL Loader. However, some rows have a CR/LF in their first column, enclosed by double quotes. Note that the row terminators are also CR/LF.

This is the .ctl file I am using:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'incoming_data.txt'
CONTINUEIF THIS PRESERVE (1:1) = '"'
INTO TABLE my_table
TRUNCATE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
text_column                     char(150),
date_column                     date 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
number_column                   integer external,
another_text_column             char(150) terminated by whitespace
)
```

This is concatenating the two "partial rows" correctly. However, it concatenates the two portions of the first field without any separator. I would like to insert, say, a slash between the two parts - i.e. replace the original newline in the field's data with a slash.

How do I do that?  Something like replace(:text_column,'\n','/') is not working, presumably as the continueif is removing the embedded newline.

Comment: For this kind of thing I find it useful to replace embedded special chars in data like CRLF with non-printing, non-meaningful characters like `CHR(20)` or `CHR(21)`. Then you can translate those back using either `REPLACE` or `TRANSLATE` in your SQLLoader control file.

Comment: Some sample data might be helpful; do the rows end with a terminator (`|`)? If not I think you would have to manipulate the file before loading. Also do you actually want to remove the CRLF from the data that ends up in the table, or are you trying to do that as a workaround?